# How to get input to array simply in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, input

Like c++ we can use this.

```
a[5];
copy(istream_iterator<int>(cin),istream_iterator<int>(),a);
```

Is there some simple way to get array from input in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the simple way like it

```
package userinput;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class USERINPUT {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //allow user  input;
        System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to enter?");
        int num = input.nextInt();

        int array[] = new int[num];

        System.out.println("Enter the " + num + " numbers now.");

        for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++ ) {
           array[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        //you notice that now the elements have been stored in the array .. array[]

        System.out.println("These are the numbers you have entered.");
        printArray(array);

    }

  //print the array
    public static void printArray(int arr[]){

        int n = arr.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about simply using `System.console().readLine("Array (use , as separator)? ").split(",")`? Then convert it to an `int[]` array (there are tons of util libraries to do that).